# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, right-to-left

I have this error. I know the casting conversion and other conversion, but how can I convert to `System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft`?

**Code:**

```
this.RightToLeft = false; // Here is the problem
this.Text = "Do you speak english ?";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want *either* this:

```
this.RightToLeftLayout = false;
```

or this:

```
this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
```

The [`Form.RightToLeftLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout.aspx) property *is* of type `bool`, but [`Control.RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) is of type [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.righttoleft.aspx) (an enum). It's hard to tell which you want based only on your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to cast here because the [`Control.RightToLeft` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) does **not** accept a value of type `bool`. Rather, it's an enum; specifically, the enum type with the same name, [`RightToLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.righttoleft.aspx).

You need to use one of *those* values. Either:

- `RightToLeft.No` (the default)
- `RightToLeft.Inherit`
- `RightToLeft.Yes`

Answer (score 0):

The type of `this.RightToLeft` is of `System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft` as you mention, which has members `Yes` and `No` (and `Inherit`, which uses the parent form's value).  You can use this logic for the assignment:

```
this.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
```

You can avoid the long type name with the proper `import`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.righttoleft.aspx) enumerattion, like

```
RightToLeft.No
```